# Angular Service Worker fetch errors

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker

Regarding our Angular 6 web application with service workers: We're struggling with this `service worker` related error when accessing our QA website via Chrome - `Site can't be reached`.

A temp fix is to open `f12 dev console` and choose `Update on reload` and `Bypass for network` checkboxes, then refresh the page to access the site.

Here's the error showing in F12 dev console:

[image]

One obvious thing we noticed is the path to our `index.html` page, which is wrong. It's trying to reference index.html at the domain root - i.e. https://mydomain.myserver.com/index.html - whereas it should reference https://mydomain.myserver.com/mytestwebsite/index.html .

Perhaps there's a problem in our ngsw config file :

```js
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [{
    "name": "app",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/index.html",
        "/*.css",
        "/*.js"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**"
      ]
    }
  }],
  "dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "api-performance",
      "urls": [
        "/api/**"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "strategy": "freshness",
        "maxSize": 100,
        "maxAge": "6h"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "custom-server",
      "urls": [
        "**/CustomServer.aspx?**"
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "strategy": "performance",
        "maxSize": 100,
        "maxAge": "1d"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Any advice regarding the optimal way of setting up Angular service workers is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can overcome this by changing path in 
app.module.ts .
like this

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('/mytestwebsite/ngsw-worker.js', {
  enabled: environment.production
})
```

this will change the scope of the service worker installation to your deployment folder.

the default worker activation without the above modification is installed on the parent url

```
https://mydomain.myserver.com/index.html so when you enter https://mydomain.myserver.com/ngsw-worker.js it will return the file.
```

you need the worker to work on https://mydomain.myserver.com/mytestwebsite/ path. so changing the path of installation of the service worker will fix the issue.